# TSQL Date Format to match jQuery plugin

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using a plugin that has the date field formatted like this: `06/05/2014 12:00`. I have it stored in the database as a datetime field.

I am now pulling it back out to the page to be able to edit. How can I convert the date time so this same format?

I looked on here but couldn't find the same output. http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using jQuery's datetimepicker? If so take this sexy code for a ride:

```
$('#timePicker').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
```